# i overwritten GRUB2 with Legacy GRUB; how can i bring GRUB2 back?

Tags: linux, grub

during moving my root partition, i used the old grub and installed the old grub on harddisk:

```
grub
grub > setup (hd0)
```

now how could i install GRUB2 on harddisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to boot to a Linux installation that has Grub2, and run its `grub-install` command, probably as `grub-install /dev/sda`.

If you're having trouble booting your existing installation, try a rescue/live Linux on CD or USB. Many distributions' install disk are capable of restoring the bootloader. An OS-agnostic rescue disk for Grub2 is [SuperGRUB2Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/SuperGRUB2Disk).

The Ubuntu wiki has some information on [reinstalling Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202) which may be useful even if you're not running Ubuntu. There is now an official [Grub2 manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/index.html), as well.

Comment: many thanks. the reference to GRUB2 and using live CD helped me.